# Xamarin Android terminate the only fragment that is created

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am doing an app, and I wanted to implement a camera functionality, I did so via a fragment, So on button click the new fragment is created and added. And once a photo is taken it gets saved to the memory, I also have a FileObserver in my original (MainActivity) which checks when the picture was taken/overridden and via that event, which is inside the MainActivity, I want to terminate the camera fragment and return to my MainActivity.

I start the fragment like this:

```
FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.Main, CameraFragment.NewInstance()).Commit();
```

I was following this demo example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android50-camera2basic/

And I dont know what to call in my MainActivity to end the fragment and return to my MainActivity

Comment: How about a FragmentTransaction where you call `Remove()` to remove the displayed fragment?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Tried that already, When I put CameraFragment thats a type so it doesnt work but when I try to do GetFragment i dont know which bundle to add or key, the documentation doesnt provide much on fragmentManager that I could find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/managing-fragments#communicating-with-fragments

Comment: You may want to either find it by tag, or keep a reference to your fragment to remove that specific instance later.

Comment: you can check the api about fragmentmanager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.fragmentmanager?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12